# getting a byte literal to a u64 literal

Tags: rust

I understand based on [this link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#byte-literals) that b'2'u64 should be allowed but I'm getting a error

```
error: suffixes on byte literals are invalid
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     b'1'u64
  |     ^^^^^^^ invalid suffix `u64`

error: could not compile `testcon` due to previous error
```

I found i could use `b'1' as u8 as u32` but that is not allowed to use it in a `match`.
is there any way to get a literal that is linked to a byte literal and can be used for `match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separately on the same reference page is [a section on suffixes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#suffixes). Here's the relevant paragraphs (emphasis mine):

> Any kind of literal (string, integer, etc) with any suffix is valid **as a token**.
>
> However, suffixes on literal tokens which are interpreted as literal expressions or patterns are restricted. **Any suffixes are rejected on non-numeric literal tokens**, and numeric literal tokens are accepted only with suffixes from the list below.

So `b'1'u64` is *lexically* valid, and can even be parsed and used by macros. However, it is not *semantically* valid. And in the linked reference, a byte literal creates just that: a single `u8`.

---

For something you can use in a `match` pattern, you could create a constant:

```
const ONE: u64 = b'1' as u64;

match x {
    ONE => ...,
    ...
}
```